# Akka, Play, Ebean: Remoting and sending model objects as messages

Tags: playframework, akka, ebean, akka-remote-actor

We're working on an architecture where we should be able to send objects from a Play! application to a series of Akka remote systems.

The `models.*` package is shared across all the systems, but the models are persisted only on the Play! application based on user input. Now, for intensive operations, these model objects are passed to remote actors to be handled. The remote actors aren't meant to persist the objects at all, but just to operate on them based on the data.

So, for example, if a user needs to be updated on a third party API, the object from the DB is just sent to the remote actor;

```
remoteActorSelection ! User.find.byId(100)
```

We are using `Ebean` with Play!.

Now the roadblock with this is that on the Akka system side, Ebean throws an error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: DataSource user is null?
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.sql.DataSourcePool.<init>(DataSourcePool.java:204)
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.getDataSourceFromConfig(DefaultServerFactory.java:419)
```

Which, in my opinion just means that since the model classes extend `Model`, Ebean expects to connect to a database.
Which defeats the purpose.

How can this be solved? Serialisation isn't an option.

Comment: If you're sending it remotely, serialization is required because Akka has to write those models to the wire somehow.

Comment: @Ryan But then why does a non persisted object of the same type get sent to Akka? For example, something like `remoteActorSelection ! (new User("random@email.com"))` works.

Comment: My point was that you said serialization isn't an option, but serialization is required by the nature of Akka.  It's happening either way.

Comment: @Ryan I phrased that wrongly, then. I meant Json serialisation, for example, wasn't an option.